# How to change the dimension for a button in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-theming

I have this button in Sencha Touch 2, I would need to resize to "small"I need change its height. Could you please provide me a sample of code? thanks

```
  navigationBar: {

        items:[{
            xtype: 'button',              
            text: 'Settings',
            itemId: 'settingsButton',
            align: 'right',
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: 'settings9'
        }],
        ui: 'custom-toolbar-top-1L'
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice to do this with css, or more precise with [Sencha Theming](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/theming).

Start point to your question is [Sencha Kitchen sink samples](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/touch-build/examples/production/kitchensink/index.html#demo/buttons)

In short you have to add ui: 'small' to button's configuration

Cheers, Oleg